# JBOSS Configurations

Tags: session, configuration, parameters, jboss

Disclaimer: I am more of a programmer and have little knowledge of JBOSS.

When we deployed the system, it works properly in the test environment. However in production, since there are multiple users and a lot of data are being updated/saved, some issues occurred. Double updates are being created, some functions are not working unless the server is restartedd. I'm thinking that this may be corrected by modifying whatever session or memory parameter JBOSS has. So we could prevent restarting the server every time an error occurs.

Question: What parameter or jboss configuration should we edit to accommodate multiple users and a large number of transactions.

Comment: What is the question? And what are the issues you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry. I included the question. I have this theory that most of the issue occurred (duplicate records, no data are retrieved, some data aren't saved properly, etc.). I'm not sure if the cause of this is the browser caching or jboss sessions. So I'm trying to limit the possibilities.

Comment: What version of Application Server are you using? It is important to specify as AS7 has been released and the methods for config and administration are updated (and in many cases, completely rewritten).

Answer (score 2):

You need to investigate the reason for your application not behaving the way you want to. Some Points you can consider :

1. Log request in Jboss support.
2. Try increasing Java heap size. (this can be done by editing entry in standalone.conf).
3. Try enabling gc logs to see , if your garbage is properly collected or not.
4. Check for memory leakage in code.
5. try to analyze thread dumps to check whether some of your threads are being blocked or not.
6. See what if you server CPU and memory Utilization is high or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of JBoss you are using, but if you are wanting to increase the JVM memory you can modify the following line in the run.bat file in your bin folder:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m
```

Xms = Minimum size and Xmx is Maximum size. If you think it is due to lack of resources, you may want to increase it to something like this:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

Does everything work normally with only 1 or very few users using the system? To me it seems more like a coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Heap size of JVM and set it according to Machine RAM available.

You must have performance testing done before you deploy to production. You can check the behaviour of your code in performance testing using some monitoring tool or JMX tool.

Tune the paramter like Heap size, GC alogrithm, you might want to define fixed size of young generation

Tune the thread as well.
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ThreadPoolConfiguration?_sscc=t